# Does Kotlin have a type similar to Swift Optional?

Tags: swift, kotlin

Swift has an enum type `Optional` right in its core library, which means you can look at some of the code for how Swift deals with optionals (the `??` operator for example) and you can even add your own extensions to it.

Does Kotlin have a similar type in its base library? Or is all of Kotlin's nullable types handled at the language/syntax/compiler level? I've read through [the very spartan Null Safety section of the Kotlin manual](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-null-types), but didn't find any hints to a specific null wrapper type.

Comment: Java has java.util.Optional, but Kotlin doesn't really need it since it has distinct types for nullable values. Any specific thing you wonder how to do in Kotlin?

Comment: Well, yes. I wondering if I can implement something like Optional.map() in Kotlin. But there would need to be a distinct (generic?) type for optionals like there is in Swift.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#map-nullable-value-if-not-null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `?` suffix is the equivalent of Swift's `Optional`, except it's not an enum like in Swift, because it's not a first-class value, it backs onto the JVM's primitive `null` instead.

You can add extensions on nullable types, something like this:

```
fun <T> Collection<T>?.isNullOrEmpty(): Boolean {
    return this == null || isEmpty()
}
```

It's not quite the same as Swift because you need to choose a base class (e.g. `Collection<T>` here) but it's similar in power.

You also have access to Java 8's `java.util.Optional<T>` in Kotlin, but that's just a mess and best avoided.

Comment: The explanation I was looking for; Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin datatypes are non-nullable by default.  You make a nullable datatype by appending a question mark:

```
var a: String = "Hello!"   // non-nullable
var b: String? = null  // nullable
```

Conversions from a non-nullable value to a nullable type are automatic.  There is also Swift-like null-propagating syntax.

Answer (score 0):

No , there is no in build features in kotlin, but we can get same optional unwraping syntax using `inline fun`

```
inline fun <T:Any?> T?.unwrap(callback: (T)-> Unit) : Boolean {
    return if (this != null) {
        this?.let(callback)
        true
    }else {
        false
    }
}
```

**Uses:**

```
        val  name : String? = null
        val  rollNo : String? = ""
        var namesList: ArrayList<String>?  = null

        if (name.unwrap { name ->

                Log.i("Dhiru", "Name have value on it  $name")

            })else if ( rollNo.unwrap {
                Log.i("Dhiru","Roll have value on it")

            }) else if (namesList.unwrap {  namesList  ->
                Log.i("Dhiru","This is Called when names list have value ")
            })  {
             Log.i("Dhiru","No Field have value on it ")
        }
```